# Routing is happening in url but page is not rendering in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Instructor.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ListCoursesComponent from './ListCoursesComponent'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import CourseComponent from './CourseComponent';

export default class extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <h1>Instructor Application</h1>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={ ListCoursesComponent }/>
                    <Route exact path="/courses" component=ListCoursesComponent }/>
                    <Route path="courses/:id" component={ CourseComponent }/> 
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

ListCoursesComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CourseDataService from '../service/CourseDataService';

const INSTRUCTOR = 'in28minutes'
export default class ListCoursesComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            courses: [],
            message: null
        }
        this.refreshCourses = this.refreshCourses.bind(this);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
        this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.refreshCourses();
    }

    refreshCourses(){
        CourseDataService.retrieveAllCourses(INSTRUCTOR)
            .then(
            Response => {
                console.log(Response);
                this.setState({ courses: Response.data })
            }
        )
    }

    handleDelete(id){
        CourseDataService.deleteCourse(INSTRUCTOR, id).then(Response=>{
            this.setState({
                message: `Delete of course ${id} successful`
            })
            this.refreshCourses();
        })
    }

    handleUpdate(id){
        console.log('update '+id)
        this.props.history.push(`/courses/${id}`)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h3>All courses</h3>
                {this.state.message && <div className="alert alert-success">{ this.state.message }</div>}
                <div className="container">
                    <table className="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                                <th>Update</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                this.state.courses.map(course =>
                                    <tr key={course.id}>
                                        <td>{ course.id }</td>
                                        <td>{ course.description }</td>
                                        <td><button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => this.handleDelete(course.id)}>Delete</button></td>
                                        <td><button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => this.handleUpdate(course.id)}>Update</button></td>
                                    </tr>                                    
                                    )
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

CourseComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class CourseComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Course details</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Actually ListCoursesComponent.js routing is happening and it rendering on the page.When I clicked on update button it has to render CourseComponent.js component, it is displaying only

```html
<h1>Instructor application</h1> not displaying this tag <h3>Course details</h3>, but URL is changing rendering is not happening
```

Comment: `component=ListCoursesComponent }/>` is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

In 'Instructor.jsx', Have you tried change

```
<Route path="courses/:id" .../>
```

to

```
<Route path="/courses/:id" .../>
```

the starting '/' matters

Comment: Thank you, Now it's rendering